# Android Studio: Out of Memory Error (Activity Lifecycle?)

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

The app I'm creating has 3 buttons in the main activity.  Each button goes to a different activity with a drawable animation when clicked.

When I click one of the buttons, an activity with a drawable animation appears as expected.  If I go back to the main activity and click a different button, a message box pops up that says "Unfortunately, Application has stopped".

This is the error that logcat gives:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 8294412 byte
>   allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 6MB until OOM

I think it might have something to do with the activity lifecycle.  The three buttons work through a switch statement that starts each buttons associated activity, and I have tried putting `finish();` and `onDestroy();` in what seems like every logical location with no luck.

Another idea I've had is to only have one activity, but pass a different animation to this activity depending on which button is pushed. But I think this method would require quite a bit of code changing.

Comment: please add some code to your question. show the code that fails with this error and point the line.

Comment: possibly a memory leak. If the first Activity is leaked and you try to open another then you have two activities with drawables in memory. But no way to know for sure unless you show the code for the Activity with the drawable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is likely the size of these animations and the timing of when the second one is being loaded whilst the first one is still in memory. You should initialise the animation in onResume and clear it from memory in onPause in order to make sure that the animation is only consuming resources when needed.

Comment: I agree, I think that is the issue...I have tried adding the following before and after onCreate.

public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();  
    }

public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();  
    }

Is this incorrect?  The problem persists so I would assume it is...

Comment: You need to put the code that initialises the animation into onResume, and likewise, clear that animation on onPause.